# Multiple upload fields on same form

Tags: php, mysql

Currently I have this file upload form

```
 <form class="form-horizontal" action="" method="post" role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">                         
     <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="upload_sheet">sheets:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="file" class="form-control" id="file" name="file" id="upload_sheet">
            </div>
     </div>                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
     <div class="form-group"> 
            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-4">
                <input type="submit" name="add" value="Add New" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">
            </div>
     </div>
</form>
```

And this is php part

```
if (count($_FILES["file"]) > 0) {

$folderName = "uploads/";

$sql = "INSERT INTO document_upload ( upload_sheet, upload_size, upload_type, document_path) 
                VALUES ( :upload_sheet, :upload_size, :upload_type, :document_path)";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);

    if ($permitted) {

      $fileSize = $_FILES['file']['size'];
      $fileType = $_FILES['file']['type'];
      $fileName = $_FILES['file']['name'];
      $tmpName  = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

  $ext = substr(strrchr($fileName, "."), 1);
  $randName = rand(10000, 990000) . '-' .$fileName;
      $filepath = $folderName . $randName;

      if (!move_uploaded_file($tmpName, $filepath)) {
        $emsg .= "Error while - <strong>" . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "</strong> is uploaded. Please try again. <br>";
      } else {
        $smsg .= "The file <strong>" . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "</strong> is added successfully. <br>";
        /*             * ****** insert into database starts ******** */

        try {
          $stmt->bindValue(":upload_sheet", $randName, PDO::PARAM_STR);              
          $stmt->bindValue(":upload_size", $fileSize, PDO::PARAM_STR);
          $stmt->bindValue(":upload_type", $fileType, PDO::PARAM_STR); 
          $stmt->bindValue(":document_path", $filepath, PDO::PARAM_STR);                                                                                                                 

          $stmt->execute();
          $result = $stmt->rowCount();
          if ($result > 0) {
            // file uplaoded successfully.
          } else {
            // failed to insert into database.
          }
        } catch (Exception $ex) {
          $emsg .= "<strong>" . $ex->getMessage() . "</strong>. <br>";
        }
      }
    } else {
      $emsg .= "This file <strong>" . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "</strong> isn't permitted. <br>";
    }
```

This is working perfectly and I'm able to add new file into database. My question is how can I add second `<input>` for file on that form and what I need to change on php part in order to upload 2 files from 2 input fields on the same form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for your form part : you can add **multiple** at the end of the *input* tag like this:

```
<input type="file" class="form-control" id="file" name="file" id="upload_sheet" multiple>
<input type="file" class="form-control" id="file" name="file2" id="upload_sheet2" multiple>
```

Change *name* and *id* for the 2nd input to make it unique.

Then the user can select more then 1 file and add them to the upload.

**multiple** is supported since [HTML5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_select#Multiple_file_selection)

for 2 different input in PHP you can change your first **if** statement

```
if (count($_FILES["file"]) > 0 || count($_FILES["file2"]) > 0) {

 //your logic/uploading
```

}

**||** = **OR** if its required both fields have files you do **&&** = **AND**

Comment: The next stage of idea will be this... To have 2 fields for files upload and they will be multiple. Is this possible? Let's say 2 input fields each will accept up to 10 files?

Comment: Specify why exactly you want 2 input fields for the user? @JordanVit offcourse that can be possible but maybe with the reasoning behind it we can come to a proper solution :)

Comment: Because they are two different fields. One is `project` second is `project_plan`. Then later when admin enter he will see on the table if specific user is uploaded his ready project and his project_plan.

Comment: Now is more clear and I just tried this but doesn't save anything in the database and in the folder there is only one file. From second input file field

Comment: @JordanVit did you add  $_FILES['file2']['name'] ? don't forget in your logic to make the proper adjustments.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108636/discussion-between-baboizk-and-jordan-vit).

Answer (score 1):

You simply add the html tags like so:

```
<input type="file" class="form-control" id="file2" name="file2" >
```

Make sure to have different 'name' attributes when you POST, because it is what PHP uses to identify the data from the form.

And then in PHP, simply access the file using

```
$_FILES['file2']['name']
```

Side note, make sure you have just one 'id' for html elements to avoid ambiguity. (Your file element in the form has 2 id fields). Hope this helps!

Comment: Do I need to add second `type`, `size`, `file_path` in mysql table?

Comment: @JordanVit, if each of your records need to store multiple files (and you are not concerned about good database design), you can add these fields to the table. However, if you do want to do good database design, look up "3rd Normal" databases. In the case of 3rd normal design, you would make a new table called 'UserFiles', with user_id, and the file details. So you can store multiple records of user files in the table

Comment: It wont be much complex page and I believe for now I don't need to normalize database.

Comment: No worries! Good luck!

Comment: Thank's but still didn't understand if I need second filetype, filesize and filepath for the second file?

Comment: If your files are identical, you don't need to. If they're completely different, you need them.

Comment: Well they can be same type.. but they will contain different data in them for sure

Comment: As long as the types and other meta data are the same, you can use the same fields

Comment: doesn't work like this.. first file is saved in folder second file is saved in database

Answer (score 1):

**HTML (list of files):**

```
<input type="file" class="form-control" name="files[]" id="upload_sheet_0">
<input type="file" class="form-control" name="files[]" id="upload_sheet_1">
...
```

This structure is also pretty to simply add more file via click.
cue: JavaScript: `.append('<input name="files[]" />')`

**PHP:**

```
foreach($_FILES['files'] AS $file) {
   handleUpload($file); // contains your upload-logic
}
```

Comment: Thank's for the answer but I'm not sure that I understand this.

Comment: $_FILES['files'] contains now an array of your want to uploaded files. In your example: $fileSize = $_FILES['files'][0]['size'] shows the size of first upload-file.